# I get ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I write this query and when I run it I get

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

I check with many online SQL query checker and all of them answered it is correct can any body help me what's the problem

```
select *
from T_TimelineItem ti
where ti.C_HIDE = 0
  and ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS = 4335
  and exists(select *
             from T_Business b
                      inner join MM_BIZ_GUILDS g on b.C_ID = g.ID1
             where b.C_ID = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
               and g.ID2 in (49))
  and (CASE ti.C_TYPE
           WHEN 1 then ti.C_ID in (select po.C_TIMELINEID
                                   from T_PRODUCT pr
                                            inner join T_POST po on po.C_ID = pr.F_POST
                                   where po.F_BUSINESS = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
                                     and pr.F_GUILD in (49))
           WHEN 8 THEN ti.C_ID in (select po.C_TIMELINEID
                                   from T_COMPETITION com
                                            inner join T_POST po on po.C_ID = com.F_POST
                                   where po.F_BUSINESS = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
                                     and com.F_GUILD in (49)) END);
```

Comment: What line does the error mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `case` in `where` clauses

```
and (ti.C_TYPE = 1 and ti.C_ID in (select po.C_TIMELINEID
                               from T_PRODUCT pr
                                        inner join T_POST po on po.C_ID = pr.F_POST
                               where po.F_BUSINESS = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
                                 and pr.F_GUILD in (49)))

or (ti.C_TYPE = 8 and ti.C_ID in (select po.C_TIMELINEID
                               from T_COMPETITION com
                                        inner join T_POST po on po.C_ID = com.F_POST
                               where po.F_BUSINESS = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
                                 and com.F_GUILD in (49)) END))
```

Comment: thanks it worked. I didn't know we cant use case in where clause.

Comment: You can use `case` sometimes but it is always better to use simple boolean logic instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed multiple in cause you can use equal easily for single value comparison and you don't need to select all the column inside `exists`

```
select *
from T_TimelineItem ti
where ti.C_HIDE = 0
  and ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS = 4335
  and exists(select 1
             from T_Business b
                      inner join MM_BIZ_GUILDS g on b.C_ID = g.ID1
             where b.C_ID = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
               and g.ID2 = 49
             )
  and (ti.C_TYPE=1
           and ti.C_ID in (select po.C_TIMELINEID
                                   from T_PRODUCT pr
                                            inner join T_POST po 
                                  on po.C_ID = pr.F_POST
                                   where po.F_BUSINESS = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
                                     and pr.F_GUILD =49
                             )
           or ( ti.C_TYPE=8 and
                            ti.C_ID in (select po.C_TIMELINEID
                            from T_COMPETITION com
                            inner join T_POST po on po.C_ID = com.F_POST
                            where po.F_BUSINESS = ti.F_RELATED_BUSINESS
                            and com.F_GUILD =49
                      )
```

Comment: I wanted to check some hql cause I  use "in (49)". list of ids will be write instead of 49